# Qt keyPressEvent not called properly when HOLDING down specific keys (shift key)

Tags: qt, keyboard, keypress, shift

Normally when the key is hold down the keyPressEvent function is called
as often as QApplication::keyboardInputInterval() is set to.
However it does not work for keys like shift,ctrl or alt.

this is executing properly:

```
void Renderer::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
  if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape) qDebug() << "executing";
}
```

this is executed only once when the button is pressed:

```
void Renderer::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
  if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Shift) qDebug() << "executing";
}
```

the only difference is `Qt::Key_Shift` and `Qt::Key_Escape`.
Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do as follows.

```
if(QApplication::keyboardModifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier)
{
     //Things need to do while holding SHIFT key.
}

else
{
     //Things need to do while not holding SHIFT key.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's by design. Modifier keys don't have autorepeat, it'd be pointless. They are either down or up.

If you need it (what for?), you need to implement modifier key autorepeat yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply I'll try that.

I need for alligment QGraphicsLineItem that is being drawn (something like in many graphics editors where you can hold shift and the line can be only rotated by 45*n degrees)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answer is too late to help you with your application, but there is a work around to using repeating events.

```
bool shiftHeld = false;

void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
  if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Shift)
    shiftHeld = true;
}

void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
  if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Shift)
    shiftHeld = false;
}
```

Just check the `shiftHeld` variable to see if shift is currently held and alter your application's behavior accordingly.